# Change menu bar position on tvOS

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'd like to change the position of menubar from top to left on tvOS.
With `Menu Bar Template`, can we change the position of menu bar by for example changing the style of it?

I've looked over the TVML Styles of Apple's document, but I couldn't find anything about changing the position of menubar.

If I cannot change it with Menu Bar Template, I'm thinking to try to use UIKit instead of TVML Template...

I appreciate any comments for it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can't change the position of the menu bar, Apple is trying to keep the UI the same all over the Apps. Which is good for your users.

You should probably look into other templates that have a vertical layout, like the stack template, or [paradeTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ParadeTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH37-SW1) which probably makes more sense in your use case.

But the worse case you can create your own with [tvinterfacefactory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmlkit/tvinterfacefactory?language=objc) with native code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already checked other templates and I think I need to use `divTemplate` or that `TV Interface Factory` for my case.